# how to get notified AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN after AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS

Tags: android

I'm trying to monitor the audio focus using this command (pseudo-code)

```
requestAudioFocus(AudioManager, STREAM_MUSIC, AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
```

at onAudioFocusChange I can recieve all kind of status codes and my problem is that after recieving **AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS** i'm supposed to abandon the focus even though I want to know when the application that requested it stopped, but after getting AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS you won't get notified even if you dont unregister&abandon the audio focus.

so my question is what can I do to know when that app finished using the audio or get a **AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN** ?

I'm using API level 15 if that helps.

Thanks in advance for any help or idea.